# Add double quotes around fields in AWK script output?

Tags: linux, shell, magento, awk

I have written an awk script that converts a distributor flatfile into a CSV importable into Magento. This file is semi-colon delimited.

It is not putting quotes around each field like the importer requires. It works fairly well, but is causing some issues on the data import without the enclosing double quotes. I spent a couple hours trying to figure out how to add this to the existing script, without much luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated - I am pretty new to AWK.

**Current Output**

```
store;websites;attribute_set;type;category_ids;sku;has_options;name;meta_title;meta_description;image;small_image;thumbnail;url_key;url_path;config_attributes;custom_design;page_layout;options_container;country_of_manufacture;msrp_enabled;msrp_display_actual_price_type;gift_message_available;rsr_pn;manufacturer_pn;price;special_price;cost;weight;msrp;status;visibility;manufacturer;enable_googlecheckout;tax_class_id;is_recurring;description;short_description;meta_keyword;custom_layout_update;news_from_date;news_to_date;special_from_date;special_to_date;custom_design_from;custom_design_to;qty;min_qty;use_config_min_qty;is_qty_decimal;backorders;use_config_backorders;min_sale_qty;use_config_min_sale_qty;max_sale_qty;use_config_max_sale_qty;is_in_stock;low_stock_date;notify_stock_qty;use_config_notify_stock_qty;manage_stock;use_config_manage_stock;stock_status_changed_auto;use_config_qty_increments;qty_increments;use_config_enable_qty_inc;enable_qty_increments;is_decimal_divided;stock_status_changed_automatically;use_config_enable_qty_increments;product_name;store_id;product_type_id;product_status_changed;product_changed_websites;gallery;related;upsell;crosssell;tier_prices;associated;bundle_options;grouped;group_price_price;downloadable_options;super_attribute_pricing;product_tags
admin;base;Default;simple;2,35,36;844802016148;0;5.11 HOLSTER SHIRT L WHITE;;;/5/1/511-40011-010-L_1.jpg;/5/1/511-40011-010-L_1.jpg;/5/1/511-40011-010-L_1.jpg;511-40011-010-L;511-40011-010-L.html;;;No layout updates;Block after Info Column;;Use config;Use config;No;511-40011-010-L;40011;74.99;;48.00;5;74.99;Enabled;Catalog, Search;5.11 Tactical;Yes;Taxable Goods;No;5.11 Tactical Short Sleeve Shirt L White Holster Shirt Crew 40011;5.11 Tactical Short Sleeve Shirt L White Holster Shirt Crew 40011;;;;;;;;;0;0;1;0;0;1;1;1;0;1;1;;;1;0;1;0;1;0;1;0;0;0;1;5.11 HOLSTER SHIRT L WHITE;0;simple;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
```

**Desired Output**

```
"store";"websites";"attribute_set";"type";"category_ids";"sku";"has_options";"name";"meta_title";"meta_description";"image";"small_image";"thumbnail";"url_key";"url_path";"config_attributes";"custom_design";"page_layout";"options_container";"country_of_manufacture";"msrp_enabled";"msrp_display_actual_price_type";"gift_message_available";"rsr_pn";"manufacturer_pn";"price";"special_price";"cost";"weight";"msrp";"status";"visibility";"manufacturer";"enable_googlecheckout";"tax_class_id";"is_recurring";"description";"short_description";"meta_keyword";"custom_layout_update";"news_from_date";"news_to_date";"special_from_date";"special_to_date";"custom_design_from";"custom_design_to";"qty";"min_qty";"use_config_min_qty";"is_qty_decimal";"backorders";"use_config_backorders";"min_sale_qty";"use_config_min_sale_qty";"max_sale_qty";"use_config_max_sale_qty";"is_in_stock";"low_stock_date";"notify_stock_qty";"use_config_notify_stock_qty";"manage_stock";"use_config_manage_stock";"stock_status_changed_auto";"use_config_qty_increments";"qty_increments";"use_config_enable_qty_inc";"enable_qty_increments";"is_decimal_divided";"stock_status_changed_automatically";"use_config_enable_qty_increments";"product_name";"store_id";"product_type_id";"product_status_changed";"product_changed_websites";"gallery";"related";"upsell";"crosssell";"tier_prices";"associated";"bundle_options";"grouped";"group_price_price";"downloadable_options";"super_attribute_pricing";"product_tags"
"admin";"base";"Default";"simple";"2,35,36";"844802016148";"0";"5.11 HOLSTER SHIRT L WHITE";"";"";"/5/1/511-40011-010-L_1.jpg";"/5/1/511-40011-010-L_1.jpg";"/5/1/511-40011-010-L_1.jpg";"511-40011-010-L";"511-40011-010-L.html";"";"";"No layout updates";"Block after Info Column";"";"Use config";"Use config";"No";"511-40011-010-L";"40011";"74.99";"";"48.00";"5";"74.99";"Enabled";"Catalog, Search";"5.11 Tactical";"Yes";"Taxable Goods";"No";"5.11 Tactical Short Sleeve Shirt L White Holster Shirt Crew 40011";"5.11 Tactical Short Sleeve Shirt L White Holster Shirt Crew 40011";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"0";"0";"1";"0";"0";"1";"1";"1";"0";"1";"1";"";"";"1";"0";"1";"0";"1";"0";"1";"0";"0";"0";"1";"5.11 HOLSTER SHIRT L WHITE";"0";"simple";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"
```

**Script - rsrimport.awk**

```
#!/bin/awk -f
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Copyright (c) 2012 - 2013 John Steensen <john.steensen@live.com>
# All rights reserved. No warranty, explicit or implicit, provided.
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# AWK Processing
# Updated 03DEC2012@1552 MST
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Warnings/Dependancy Notes
# AWK
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
BEGIN {
FS=";";
OFS=";";
CATEGORY="47";
IMAGE="imagepathfail";
URLKEY="urlkeyfail";
URLPATH="urlpathfail";
print "store", "websites", "attribute_set", "type", "category_ids", "sku", "has_options", "name", "image", "small_image", "thumbnail", "url_key", "url_path", "page_layout", "options_container", "msrp_enabled", "msrp_display_actual_price_type", "gift_message_available", "rsr_pn", "manufacturer_pn", "price", "cost", "weight", "msrp", "manufacturer", "status", "is_recurring", "visibility", "enable_googlecheckout", "tax_class_id", "description", "short_description", "qty", "min_qty", "use_config_min_qty", "is_qty_decimal", "backorders", "use_config_backorders", "min_sale_qty", "use_config_min_sale_qty", "max_sale_qty", "use_config_max_sale_qty", "is_in_stock", "notify_stock_qty", "use_config_notify_stock_qty", "manage_stock", "use_config_manage_stock", "stock_status_changed_auto", "use_config_qty_increments", "qty_increments", "use_config_enable_qty_inc", "enable_qty_increments", "is_decimal_divided", "stock_status_changed_automatically", "use_config_enable_qty_increments", "product_name", "store_id", "product_type_id";
}
{
# DEFINE CATEGORY
if ($4=="1") CATEGORY="2,3,4";
else if ($4=="2") CATEGORY="2,3,7";
else if ($4=="3") CATEGORY="2,3,8";
else if ($4=="4") CATEGORY="2,3,22,23";
else if ($4=="5") CATEGORY="2,3,5";
else if ($4=="7") CATEGORY="2,3,6";
else if ($4=="8") CATEGORY="2,27,28";
else if ($4=="9") CATEGORY="2,27,29";
else if ($4=="10") CATEGORY="2,9,13";
else if ($4=="11") CATEGORY="2,9,14";
else if ($4=="12") CATEGORY="2,35,38";
else if ($4=="13") CATEGORY="2,9,16";
else if ($4=="14") CATEGORY="2,35,37";
else if ($4=="15") CATEGORY="2,19,21";
else if ($4=="16") CATEGORY="2,9,15";
else if ($4=="17") CATEGORY="2,9,16";
else if ($4=="18") CATEGORY="2,19,20";
else if ($4=="20") CATEGORY="2,27,33";
else if ($4=="21") CATEGORY="2,9,17";
else if ($4=="22") CATEGORY="2,3,22,24";
else if ($4=="23") CATEGORY="2,3,22,25";
else if ($4=="24") CATEGORY="2,9,13";
else if ($4=="25") CATEGORY="2,40,43";
else if ($4=="26") CATEGORY="2,40,44";
else if ($4=="27") CATEGORY="2,3,22,26";
else if ($4=="28") CATEGORY="2,27,31";
else if ($4=="29") CATEGORY="2,27,32";
else if ($4=="30") CATEGORY="2,27,30";
else if ($4=="31") CATEGORY="2,27,34";
else if ($4=="32") CATEGORY="2,9,11";
else if ($4=="33") CATEGORY="2,35,36";
else if ($4=="34") CATEGORY="2,9,10";
else if ($4=="35") CATEGORY="2,9,18";
else if ($4=="36") CATEGORY="2,40,42";
else if ($4=="38") CATEGORY="2,40,41";
else if ($4=="39") CATEGORY="2,40,45";
else if ($4=="40") CATEGORY="2,35,39";
else if ($4=="41") CATEGORY="2,9,12";
else if ($4=="43") CATEGORY="2,9,12";
else if ($4=="01") CATEGORY="2,3,4";
else if ($4=="02") CATEGORY="2,3,7";
else if ($4=="03") CATEGORY="2,3,8";
else if ($4=="04") CATEGORY="2,3,22,23";
else if ($4=="05") CATEGORY="2,3,5";
else if ($4=="07") CATEGORY="2,3,6";
else if ($4=="08") CATEGORY="2,27,28";
else if ($4=="09") CATEGORY="2,27,29";
else CATEGORY="47";
# DEFINE IMAGE WITH PATH.
IMAGE="/5/1/"$1"_1.jpg";
# DEFINE URL KEY
URLKEY=$1;
# DEFINE URL PATH
URLPATH=$1".html";
print "admin", "base", "Default", "simple", CATEGORY, $1, "0", $3, IMAGE, IMAGE, IMAGE, URLKEY, URLPATH, "No layout updates", "Block after Info Column", "Use config", "Use config", "No", $1, $12, $6, $7, $8, $6, $11, "Enabled", "No", "Catalog, Search", "Yes", "Taxable Goods", $14, $14, $9, "0", "1", "0", "0", "1", "1", "1", "0", "1", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "1", $3, "0", "simple";
}
END {}
```

Comment: What about changing the OFS to the following?

`OFS="\";\"";`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you want:

> add this to the existing script.

You can insert additional `\"\"` in each argument of `print` like this:

`print "\"admin\"", "\"base\"", ...`

**Edited:**

Yes, perhaps seting OFS is better solution:

`BEGIN { OFS="\";\""; } ... print "\"admin", ...., "simple\"";`

Comment: Ah, \" is the escaped double quote? Good to know!

Comment: What about changing the OFS to the following? `OFS="\";\"";`

Comment: @John Steensen +1 Good idea.

Answer (score 24):

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) $i="\""$i"\""}1' FS=";" OFS=";" input
```

Comment: It didn't work if the data contains delimiter value in quotes

Answer (score 6):

In this case I would use a `sed` expression instead of AWK.

If your data is in a file called `data.txt`, you can get it writing:

```
sed "s/;/\";\"/g;s/^/\"/;s/$/\"/" data.txt
```

That will print the result to the std output, but if you want to replace the content of the file just use `sed -i` this way:

```
sed -i "s/;/\";\"/g;s/^/\"/;s/$/\"/" data.txt
```

And that is all !!

**Explanation:**
The `sed` expression consists in three `sed` commands separated by ";" that you can run separately:

```
sed "s/;/\";\"/g
```

It makes a substitution (that is what means the first "s"), then the "/" (the default separator), ";" that is what we want to replace. Then the second separator "/", and the replacement: `\";\"` It is a sequence: escaped quote, a semicolon and a escaped quote. So with this command we will replace semicolons `;` by `";"`. The last `/g` means that each `;` will be replaced (not only the first smicolon).

If the input was `a;b;c` after this running the first command it will be `a";"b";"c`.

Now we need to add quotes in the beginning (`^` in a regular expression) and in the end (`$`). So that is what it means:

```
sed "s/^/\"/" // the first quote
```

And

```
sed "s/$/\"/" // the last quote
```

Getting the desired output:

```
"a";"b";"c"
```

Comment: So add it to the bash script versus modifying the AWK output? (Curious why that would be preferable)

Comment: Yes, you use `sed` as a bash command instead of `AWK` command. You can run `sed` and the output will be the replacement in the std output. If you want to replace the content of the file just use `sed -i` (it will not produce any output to the std). If you have any doubt about the `sed` expression, I can explain it more in detail, just let me know ;-)

Comment: Yes, actually I am very curious about what means what in the description. Doesn't quite look to be regular expressions.

Comment: I have edited my answer, explaining the `sed` commands step by step. You can run them separately to check its result. Check it !!

Comment: I went with the AWK, as it let me relatively keep things language consistant. Thanks for the explanation - I'm using it as a diving off point into better familiarizing myself with SED.

Answer (score 5):

To add quotes around the entries you could use a simple AWK loop:

**Script - simple_loop.awk**

```
BEGIN {FS=";"}
{
  for(i=1;i<NF;i++){
       printf("\"%s\";", $i); 
  }
  printf("\"%s\"\n",$NF);
}
```

For instance

```
echo "admin;base;5.11 HOLSTER SHIRT L WHITE;;" | awk -f simple_loop.awk
```

Should output

```
"admin";"base";"5.11 HOLSTER SHIRT L WHITE";"";""
```

Comment: Works perfect, however I did come up with a way to keep it inside the original script, versus adding a second operation. Thanks for the input though!

Comment: @JohnSteensen When reading the question for the first time I expected to see an example of input data and an example of expected output and actually mistook your "current output" sample for the input data. Seeing the three samples together would have helped me and possibly others to quickly understand the question.

Comment: Definitely. I really appreciate the input and will keep that in mind in the future. My apologizes.

Answer (score 1):

Let me refactor your program a bit:

```
/#!/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
    FS=";";
    OFS="\";\"";
    IMAGE="imagepathfail";
    URLKEY="urlkeyfail";
    URLPATH="urlpathfail";
    # DEFINE CATEGORY
    CATEGORY["1"] ="2,3,4";
    CATEGORY["2"] ="2,3,7";
    CATEGORY["3"] ="2,3,8";
    CATEGORY["4"] ="2,3,22,23";
    CATEGORY["5"] ="2,3,5";
    CATEGORY["7"] ="2,3,6";
    CATEGORY["8"] ="2,27,28";
    CATEGORY["9"] ="2,27,29";
    CATEGORY["10"]="2,9,13";
    CATEGORY["11"]="2,9,14";
    CATEGORY["12"]="2,35,38";
    CATEGORY["13"]="2,9,16";
    CATEGORY["14"]="2,35,37";
    CATEGORY["15"]="2,19,21";
    CATEGORY["16"]="2,9,15";
    CATEGORY["17"]="2,9,16";
    CATEGORY["18"]="2,19,20";
    CATEGORY["20"]="2,27,33";
    CATEGORY["21"]="2,9,17";
    CATEGORY["22"]="2,3,22,24";
    CATEGORY["23"]="2,3,22,25";
    CATEGORY["24"]="2,9,13";
    CATEGORY["25"]="2,40,43";
    CATEGORY["26"]="2,40,44";
    CATEGORY["27"]="2,3,22,26";
    CATEGORY["28"]="2,27,31";
    CATEGORY["29"]="2,27,32";
    CATEGORY["30"]="2,27,30";
    CATEGORY["31"]="2,27,34";
    CATEGORY["32"]="2,9,11";
    CATEGORY["33"]="2,35,36";
    CATEGORY["34"]="2,9,10";
    CATEGORY["35"]="2,9,18";
    CATEGORY["36"]="2,40,42";
    CATEGORY["38"]="2,40,41";
    CATEGORY["39"]="2,40,45";
    CATEGORY["40"]="2,35,39";
    CATEGORY["41"]="2,9,12";
    CATEGORY["43"]="2,9,12";
    CATEGORY["01"]="2,3,4";
    CATEGORY["02"]="2,3,7";
    CATEGORY["03"]="2,3,8";
    CATEGORY["04"]="2,3,22,23";
    CATEGORY["05"]="2,3,5";
    CATEGORY["07"]="2,3,6";
    CATEGORY["08"]="2,27,28";
    CATEGORY["09"]="2,27,29";
    # header
    print "store", "websites", "attribute_set", "type", "category_ids", "sku", "has_options", "name", "image", "small_image", "thumbnail", "url_key", "url_path", "page_layout", "options_container", "msrp_enabled", "msrp_display_actual_price_type", "gift_message_available", "rsr_pn", "manufacturer_pn", "price", "cost", "weight", "msrp", "manufacturer", "status", "is_recurring", "visibility", "enable_googlecheckout", "tax_class_id", "description", "short_description", "qty", "min_qty", "use_config_min_qty", "is_qty_decimal", "backorders", "use_config_backorders", "min_sale_qty", "use_config_min_sale_qty", "max_sale_qty", "use_config_max_sale_qty", "is_in_stock", "notify_stock_qty", "use_config_notify_stock_qty", "manage_stock", "use_config_manage_stock", "stock_status_changed_auto", "use_config_qty_increments", "qty_increments", "use_config_enable_qty_inc", "enable_qty_increments", "is_decimal_divided", "stock_status_changed_automatically", "use_config_enable_qty_increments", "product_name", "store_id", "product_type_id";
}

function getCategory(val) {
    return (val in CATEGORY) ? CATEGORY[val] : "47";
}

{
    # DEFINE IMAGE WITH PATH.
    IMAGE="/5/1/"$1"_1.jpg";
    # DEFINE URL KEY
    URLKEY=$1;
    # DEFINE URL PATH
    URLPATH=$1".html";
    print "\" "admin", "base", "Default", "simple", getCategory($4), $1, "0", $3, IMAGE, IMAGE, IMAGE, URLKEY, URLPATH, "No layout updates", "Block after Info Column", "Use config", "Use config", "No", $1, $12, $6, $7, $8, $6, $11, "Enabled", "No", "Catalog, Search", "Yes", "Taxable Goods", $14, $14, $9, "0", "1", "0", "0", "1", "1", "1", "0", "1", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "1", $3, "0", "simple" "\"";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, we could use printf (formated output) and double quote is obtain with \" into format string.

e.g.

gawk 'BEGIN{print "WKT,punto";}{printf "\"LINESTRING Z (%f %f 0,%f %f 0)\",\"%d"\n",$3,$2,$4,$5,$1}' Frecce_geoloc_12-24.txt

output:

```
                  $3         $2           $4         $5            $1
```

"LINESTRING Z (-72.319686 -50.609328 0,-50.609309 -72.319499 0)","6582"

"LINESTRING Z (-72.319245 -50.609215 0,-50.609195 -72.319052 0)","6583"

"LINESTRING Z (-72.318799 -50.609101 0,-50.609081 -72.318607 0)","6584"

"LINESTRING Z (-72.318366 -50.608990 0,-50.608969 -72.318169 0)","6585"